# Artefact on page when using Twig tempalting engine

Tags: php, twig

I'm using Twig with Slim.

I have a simple `for` loop in a Twig template. In that `for` loop there's another simple `if/else` statement. Code below:

```
{% for value in data_values %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ value.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.name }}</td>
            {% if value.free_delivery == 1 %}
                <td><a href="#" onclick="ajaxChangeStatusFreeDelivery( {{ value.id }}, 0)">Active</a></td>
            {% else %}
                <td><a href="#" onclick="ajaxChangeStatusFreeDelivery( {{ value.id }}, 1)">Inactive</a></td>
            {% endif %}
        <td>Dropdown goes here</td>
        <td id="edit-id-{{ value.id }}">Edit</td>
        <td id="delete-id-{{ value.id }}">Delete</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

There's nothing wrong with it, it works perfectly.

However, I'm getting this strange artefact on the page. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLBe7.png).

As soon as I remove the `else` it goes away. I think I'm misusing Twig in some way.

This not a hassle as far as programming goes. But I can't let it stay like that.

I searched around on Google but to be frank I don't even know what to search for exactly.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't forget a `var_dump()`, especially inside the `value.id` getter?

Comment: I am absolutely sure I didn't forget anything anywhere. I've looked in all the related files for about 1 hour, line by line.

Comment: can you show us the html generated with the artefact in it?